PieCloudDB error: toast table is corrputed
I'm new to PieCloudDB database, I encountered a problem that toast table is corrupted, how can I fix it?
missing chunk number 0 for toast value 32789 in pg_toast_2619


Perhaps contact the PieCloudDB team for support.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  If, however, this is a programming question,  you need to include what exactly did you do.  How did you insert data into PieCloudDB.

Well, I tried to solve this problem using my experience in PG and
surprisingly it worked.
I found the toast table based on oid, it is pg_statistic
select 2619::regclass;

then I used a stored procedure to find the bad data:
DO $$ 
DECLARE
  v_rec record; 
BEGIN 
FOR v_rec in SELECT * FROM pg_statistic loop 
raise notice ‘Parameter is:‘, v_rec.ctid; 
raise notice ‘Parameter is:’, v_rec;
END loop; 
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I found that it stopped when ctid=(50,2).
Then I selected the data of (50,2) and (50,3) respectively and found that the problem occurred at (50,3), so I deleted it
select * from pg_statistic where ctid= '(50,2)';
select * from pg_statistic where ctid= '(50,3)';

delete from pg_statistic where ctid = '(50,3)';

Finally I re-indexed and it no longer errors.
REINDEX table pg_toast.pg_toast_2619; 
REINDEX table pg_statistic; 
VACUUM ANALYZE pg_statistic;

